# Iterating over dictionary to create an instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

models.py

```
class Hire(models.Model):
    StartRentDate = models.DateField(
        auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True)
    EndRentDate = models.DateField(
        auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True)
    KMsLastShown = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    KMsToLastService = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    LastService = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    RentalPrice = models.FloatField(null=True)
```

views.py

```
StartRentDate = serializer.data.get("Hire").get("StartRentDate")
EndRentDate = serializer.data.get("Hire").get("EndRentDate")
KMsLastShown = serializer.data.get("Hire").get("KMsLastShown")
KMsToLastService = serializer.data.get("Hire").get("KMsToLastService")
LastService = serializer.data.get("Hire").get("LastService")
RentalPrice = serializer.data.get("Hire").get("RentalPrice")
hire = Hire(
    StartRentDate=StartRentDate,
    EndRentDate=EndRentDate,
    KMsLastShown=KMsLastShown,
    KMsToLastService=KMsToLastService,
    LastService=LastService,
    RentalPrice=RentalPrice,
)
```

How do I loop over `serializer.data.get('Hire')` to create the class instance `hire` from the class `Hire`
Something like

```
    HireList = []

    for HireData in serializer.data.get('Hire').values():
        HireList.append(HireData)
    
    hire = Hire(for EachModel in HireList:
       str(EachModel) = EachModel
    )
```

Comment: what's the definition of class Hire ?

Comment: Hire seems to be a dictionary -  you cannot have the same key multiple times so whats the point? You'll get the same item every time.

Comment: @PatrickArtner` Hire` is a class containing my models, `serializer.data.get('Hire')` is a  dictionary containing my data

Comment: Is that how `Hire` is actually defined (i.e. with `StartRentDate` etc. defined as class attributes rather than instance attributes)? And if so, how is `models.Model` defined?